# Dual passport US - Indonesia

Tags: usa, air-travel, dual-nationality, singapore, indonesian-citizens

I will be travelling soon to the US from Jakarta. I have both US and Indonesian passports. Indonesia does not recognise dual citizenship, yet the US requires me to enter and exit the US with my US passport. I've read that I can go to Singapore first and then fly out to the US. But which passports to use and how?

Answer (score 1):

Book two tickets: CGK<>SIN and SIN<>Wherever you're going in the US. Use the Indonesian one for Jakarta<->Singapore. Then use your US passport while entering and leaving the US.

You might want to stop over in Singapore on the way out, and pass through immigration, so that you get a Singapore entry stamp dated the day you left Jakarta. In Singapore, you can leave through the automated immigration channel, even as a tourist, so you don't get a stamp anyway. Indonesian Immigration will see your entry stamp in Singapore, and if they poke around, your return ticket CGK<>SIN. That's it. Keep your US passport well hidden.

Comment: I have friends in a similar position. :-)

Comment: so i have booked two tickets: CGK <> SIN, and SIN <> SFO. my next question is, is it ok for the Singaporean authority to let me OUT with the US passport on my next leg of flight from Singapore to SFO (considering I enter the country with my Indonesian passport? Thanks.

Comment: No. You leave Singapore (and I recommend using the automated gates) with your Indonesian passport. However during check-in (if you don't do online check-in and/or need to check in luggage), you show both passports: the Indonesian one for the entry stamp, the US one to show you don't need a visa. When you land in SFO, you show the US passport.

Comment: hi dda, on retuning from the US, do I show the airlines my Indonesian PP flying to SG, or the US PP? on exiting the immigration, I understand I have to use my US PP. Thank you much.

Comment: Show them the US passport. US citizens don't need a visa for SG or Indonesia ☺